# how to resize mobile screen to fit my content

Tags: iphone, mobile

I am having some difficulty with Adobe Device Central CS3. I am doing a mobile website test only using Html and CSS I am busy testing it via device central using all the Nokia Phones in the library.

I did a moch up in Ps using Nokia N80 which is 352px by 416px (my photoshop document)

On my Meta tags I put the following code:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<!--The iPhone will auto fit the screen -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=240, height=320, user-scalable=yes, initial-scale=0.7, maximum-scale=5.0, minimum-scale=1.0" />
<!--  adjusting Web pages to screens and adjusting Web page content size -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" /> 

<script type="text/javascript">
if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPhone') != -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('iPod') != -1))
document.location = "http://iphone.mywebsite.com/index.html";
```

When I am viewing with devices less than 352px by 416px the content gets chopped and you have to scroll sideways. From the blogs that I have read putting "viewport" is suppose to fix the problem and make the content/site scalable according to the device used.

I should also make a note that I have a wrapper div that holds everything and it has a fixed width and height.

```
#wrapper {
width:352px;
height:416px;
background:url(../images/Site-Bg_02.png) repeat;
```

}

Help!

Comment: +1 Thanks! Your question alone helped me to fit my app in android screen :-)

Comment: I am glad to have helped, by asking the question. But These days I rely on Media Queries as well as using [ one of Andy Taylor projects](http://cssgrid.net/)

Answer (score 1):

You could set your viewport width to 352, but I STRONGLY recommend instead designing your page with flexibility in mind, i.e. don't use absolute pixel values. Instead use percentage widths, and try resizing your browser (if you don't have access to actual devices to test with) to ensure that your elements fit correctly in a variety of widths.

The viewport tag will only work on certain devices, and fixed-pixel sizing is generally a mobile web no-no.

Comment: Yes Thank you for that Ben. I changed my fixed widths. I am implementing [Grid System Fluid down to mobile](http://cssgrid.net/)